# Simplify PS Command: Get-Service | where {($_.Status -eq "Stopped") -OR ($_.Status -eq "Running")}

Tags: powershell

What is the syntax to include several values in an -eq command:

This works but i think there is a way to save some typing:

```
Get-Service | where {($_.Status -eq "Stopped") -OR ($_.Status -eq "Running")}
```

Think code should look like but i don't remember exactly the syntax:

```
Get-Service | where {($_.Status -eq "Stopped"|"Running"|"...")}
```

Comment: Close, actually. `"Stopped","Running" -eq $_.Status` would work, but only since none of the enumeration values are `0`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `-contains` and the `gsv` alias :

```
gsv | where-object {@("Stopped","Running") -contains $_.Status}
```

**EDIT**: You can also use the `-match` operator:

```
gsv | where-object {$_.Status -match "Stopped|Running"}
```

**2.EDIT**: A shorter version, w/ special thanks to @Joey:

```
gsv | ? {$_.Status -match "Stopped|Running"}
```

Comment: And the `?` alias. And leave out the `@()` as that is not needed. `"Stopped","Running"` is already an array.

Comment: Well, the shortest variant would likely be `gsv|?{1,4-eq$_.Status}` using a few common golfing tricks :-)

Comment: Can't help, but it looks more and more like _PERL_ ;)

Answer (score 2):

As stated by @OcasoProtal you can compare an array of valid statuses with your target status using the `-contains` or `-notcontains` operators.

Given Status is based on an enum type you can also use that (i.e. as opposed to using string comparisons).  This adds additional validation (i.e. without manually specifying a ValidateSet), and allows you to pull a list of values from the Enum (e.g. as shown in my sample code below where `Not` is specified.

```
clear-host
[string]$ComputerName = $env:COMPUTERNAME
[string]$ServiceName = "MSSQLSERVER"


function Wait-ServiceStatus {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param
    (
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        [string]$ServiceName
        ,
        [Parameter()]
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        [string]$ComputerName = $env:COMPUTERNAME
        ,
        [switch]$Not
        ,
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
        [System.ServiceProcess.ServiceControllerStatus]$TartgetStatus
    )
    begin {
        [System.ServiceProcess.ServiceControllerStatus[]]$TargetStatuses = @($TartgetStatus)
        if ($Not.IsPresent) {

            #EXAMPLE: Build your comparison array direct from the ENUM
            $TargetStatuses = [Enum]::GetValues([System.ServiceProcess.ServiceControllerStatus]) | ?{$_ -ne $TartgetStatus}

        }
    }
    process {

        #EXAMPLE: Compare status against an array of statuses
        while ($TargetStatuses -notcontains (Get-Service -ComputerName $ComputerName -Name $ServiceName | Select -Expand Status)) {

            write-host "." -NoNewline -ForegroundColor Red
            start-sleep -seconds 1
        }
        write-host ""
        #this is a demo of array of statuses, so won't bother adding code for timeouts / etc 
    }
}
function Write-InfoToHost ($text) {write-host $text -ForegroundColor cyan} #quick thing to make our status updates distinct from function call output

Write-InfoToHost "Report Current Service Status"
get-service -Name $ServiceName -Computer $ComputerName | Select -ExpandProperty Status
Write-InfoToHost ("Stop Service at {0:HH:mm:ss}" -f (get-date))
(Get-WmiObject Win32_Service -Filter "name='$ServiceName'" -Computer $ComputerName).StopService() | out-null #use WMI to prevent waiting
Write-InfoToHost ("Invoked Stop Service at {0:HH:mm:ss}" -f (get-date)) 
Wait-ServiceStatus -ServiceName $ServiceName -TartgetStatus Stopped 
Write-InfoToHost ("Stop Service Completed at {0:HH:mm:ss}" -f (get-date)) 

Write-InfoToHost "Report Current Service Status" 
get-service -Name $ServiceName -Computer $ComputerName | Select -ExpandProperty Status

Write-InfoToHost ("Start Service at {0:HH:mm:ss}" -f (get-date)) 
(Get-WmiObject Win32_Service -Filter "name='$ServiceName'" -Computer $ComputerName).StartService() | out-null  #use WMI to prevent waiting
Write-InfoToHost ("Invoked Start Service at {0:HH:mm:ss}" -f (get-date))
Wait-ServiceStatus -ServiceName $ServiceName -Not -TartgetStatus Stopped 
Write-InfoToHost ("Service Not Stopped at {0:HH:mm:ss}" -f (get-date))
Wait-ServiceStatus -ServiceName $ServiceName -Not -TartgetStatus StartPending
Write-InfoToHost ("Service Not Start-Pending at {0:HH:mm:ss}" -f (get-date))
Write-InfoToHost "Report Current Service Status"
get-service -Name $ServiceName -Computer $ComputerName | Select -ExpandProperty Status
```

Sample Output:

```
Report Current Service Status
Running
Stop Service at 12:04:49
Invoked Stop Service at 12:04:50
.
Stop Service Completed at 12:04:51
Report Current Service Status
Stopped
Start Service at 12:04:51
Invoked Start Service at 12:04:52

Service Not Stopped at 12:04:52
..
Service Not Start-Pending at 12:04:54
Report Current Service Status
Running
```

You can also easily get Pending or "Stable State" statuses using something like this:

```
function PendingDemo([bool]$Pending) {
    write-host "Pending is $Pending" -ForegroundColor cyan
    [Enum]::GetValues([System.ServiceProcess.ServiceControllerStatus]) | ?{($_ -notlike "*Pending") -xor $Pending}
}

PendingDemo $true
""
PendingDemo $false
```

Sample Output:

```
Pending is True
StartPending
StopPending
ContinuePending
PausePending

Pending is False
Stopped
Running
Paused
```

Answer (score 1):

matching based on regex groups is the shortest and safest way always. You can use also the complementary :

```
gsv | ? {$_.status -notmatch "Paused|Running_Pending|Pause_Pending|Stop_Pending|Continue_Pending"}
```

In this case it's not the shortest, obviously; but sometime it is!

Comment: Note that the corresponding logic here is `where {($_.Status -ne "Paused") -AND ($_.Status -ne "Running_Pending")} -AND ($_.Status -ne "Pause_Pending")} -AND ($_.Status -ne "Stop_Pending")} -AND ($_.Status -ne "Continue_Pending")}`. Hope this help.